# Will a Pokemon take it's type into account when attacking with moves of a different type?

Tags: pokemon-go

I realized that in Pokemon Go, a Pokemon of a particular type might not always have an attack of the same type. For example, I have a Psyduck (Water) which has has two non Water type attacks:

- Zen Headbutt (Psychic)
- Cross Chop (Fighting).

Therefore, would this Psyduck still cause twice the damage when it attacks a Fire Type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not how Pokemon works.

You only take into account the type of the current attack that you have used.

Comment: Is there no concept of STAB (same type attack bonus) like in the main series? AKA a fire type using a fire type move gets an additional bonus to damage, on top of modifications for the enemy type resistances/weaknesses.

Comment: @shenles That I do not know, good question. I would make that it's own question as it does not pertain to this one.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the Pokemon only matters in terms of defense. The original Pokemon games have STAB (Same type attack bonus) where if a Pokemon used a move that was the same type as they are they would do an additional 50% damage with it. It is unclear whether Pokemon Go has implemented STAB.

So if your Psyduck (water) is hit by a lightning attack it will take double damage.

The attacks of your Psyduck have nothing to do with the type of the Pokemon, so whether they do extra damage or not is based on the type of the attack. So your cross chop for instance will be super effective against normal types.

[This type advantage chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeCzI.jpg) for the 6th Generation games shows which types have advantages against other types:

[image: 6th Gen type Chart]

Although note that in Pokemon Go, immunities (0x damage) do not exist and is instead a not very effective (0.5x damage) attack.

Comment: -1. The chart is somewhat misleading as it doesn't entirely apply to Pokemon Go.

Comment: I can't view the picture at work, but the URL says it's for Gen I which didn't have the Fairy Pokemon type which we now have in PoGo. So @Studoku has a point, I think.

Comment: @Ekmod Pokemon go *does* have those types. Fairy and steel were retconned into gen I. Fairy/steel/dark moves are all present. Zero-effect attacks are not.

Comment: @Studoku, Maybe because I can't view the image or my comment wasn't clear, but I'm not sure how to interpret your comment. I agreed with your first sentence about the "new type" being in PoGo in my original comment. But I'm not sure what you mean by "retconned into gen I".

Comment: @Studoku it's not wrong, maybe incomplete as it doesn't have some types, and there's no 0x in pokemon go. But it still shows which types have advantages against which types. It wasn't part of the question so I didn't feel the need to fully explain it but I thought that it would supplement well.

Comment: @Aequitas It also claims that ghost doesn't affect psychic, which is wrong.

Comment: @Studoku updated to 6th gen type chart

Comment: In the pokémon games the type is also of significance with attacking if the attack is the same type as the Pokémon. It's called STAB which stands for sametype attack bonus dealing 50% more damage. Don't know if pokémon go has it though.

Comment: @IvoBeckers good point, i've updated answer. I've done some research and it seems no one really knows if STAB is implemented or not.